# Voting information possibly exposed through the new First Posts review tool

Tags: discussion, review, privacy

I believe it's possible to deduce who upvoted or downvoted on a post using the new First Posts review tool.

For example, here's a [review](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/971) I did on DIY.SE (the site where I'm most active):

[image]

The [review history page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) (note: seeing the full history appears to be a 10k privilege) shows that I reviewed it at 23:36:21 UTC:

[image]

The [timeline](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/11874/timeline) for the question shows a downvote on the answer on September 13th:

[image: Timeline of the post in question for September 13th shows a single downvote]

Clicking through to the [user's reputation tab](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/7269/master-jak-legg?tab=reputation) shows the downvote occurred at 23:36:17 UTC:

[image]

So if the only action on the post for the day is a downvote, and there was a review committed just a few seconds after that downvote, it's not terribly hard to deduce who placed it.

This may be less of a problem on Stack Overflow and the other big sites, but for the smaller sites where there are few people reviewing, I believe this could compromise voting anonymity.

Comment: SO is a pretty busy site. Two different people doing something within a few seconds of each other on the same post is little more than a coincidence. You can't stop people from assuming you were the down-voter if you commit some other audited action, even if they are minutes apart.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree with your statement, but I draw a slightly different conclusion than I *think* you are; people already jump to conclusions about who down voted; I don't think we should make it even more easy for them to make such assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

This is true enough. However, in order for this to be used to find the down-voter you have to already suspect someone of voting on a given post and look up either their activity history... Or trawl through the review history looking for the post.

Even then, there's no *explicit* confirmation that the vote was theirs - all you know is that they did *something* on that post during the review, and the post was down-voted at around the same time. Maybe they flagged it. Maybe they left a comment (and then deleted it). Heck, maybe they voted and then later retracted their vote!

It's a trade-off between privacy and transparency, and something you should be comfortable with if you plan to spend a lot of time moderating the site - folks will just as soon go after you for voting if you left a comment soon after a down-vote was cast, or even edited.

If you encounter harassment over voting - regardless of the source or accuracy of the allegations - please flag for moderator attention.

Comment: "If you encounter harassment over voting - regardless of the source or accuracy of the allegations - please flag for moderator attention." Does that include "Why the downvote, {insert suspected downvoter name here}" comments?

Comment: Yes. Flag those instantly.